# Use composer from outside project folder

Tags: bash, composer-php

I've googled this fairly hard, but not found *this* question. I also looked at the documentation and had no luck:

To run `composer update`, the command is usually run from inside the project.

So...

```
cd /var/www/html/project
composer update
```

This works as expected.

However, as part of an update script I would like to run this in a bash script. Composer is installed globally. I would like to be able to run composer from the location of the script with a *target* folder.. something like:

```
composer update /var/www/html/project
```

(which I have tested and does not work)

My specific question:

Is there a way of running composer on a target folder?

Comment: Can you not just cd into the folder, run the compose command and then cd .. back out?

Comment: The script can be run from a number of locations. Also, it may be run as part of another script, so moving is not acceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From personal testing it is not possible to run composer against a target folder.  If you're looking to run composer from a script the best best would be something like `cd /var/www/html/project && composer update`

This will work from within your bash script, I have personally done this on other projects.

Comment: Tested this today and upon script completion I was still in my scripts folder, so I'm marking this as a correct answer.

Answer (score 5):

I know you have solved your problem doing a "cd" and a plain "composer update" but I think that it's not the correct answer.

In composer documentation page (https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#global-options) you can find the option **--working-dir (-d)** that if specified, use the given directory as working directory.

For example:

```
composer install --working-dir=/var/www
```